# How to set a view to "invisible" or "gone" when anything other then that view is clicked on

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have an app im trying to build and i have a button that when clicked turns a linearlayout to "VISIBLE",currently the only way to turn it back to "GONE" is if i click on the same button again, i would like it so it changes to "GONE" when anything other then that linearlayout is clicked on.

Here's my current code for setting the linearlayout as "VISIBLE" or "GONE":

```
box_seekbar=findViewById(R.id.box_seekbar);
box_price=findViewById(R.id.box_price);
box_price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (box_seekbar.getVisibility()==GONE){
           box_seekbar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
           }
           else{
                box_seekbar.setVisibility(GONE);
           }

           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean check = false ; 

box_seekbar=findViewById(R.id.box_seekbar);
box_price=findViewById(R.id.box_price);
box_price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (!check){
           box_seekbar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          check = true ; 
           }
           else{
                box_seekbar.setVisibility(GONE);
           check = false ; 
           }

           }
});
```

Comment: that's what i already have, what i want is for the visibility to change to "GONE" when anything else other then the "box_seekbar" is clicked on.

Comment: oook , you can add this Listener on parent element i hope understood right